# Redirecting Dropdown List With Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropdown

I just started using vuejs a few days ago. I am trying to create a dropdown list that will redirect the user to another page ((like when we do href="HomePage.aspx" in asp.net)). I would like to ask what should I replace the # to and if I should create the other page (the one that the dropdown item will redirect the user to) on the components folder. I have tried to change the `href="#"` to a .vue page that I have in the components by doing `./components/newpage` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="abc" right>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">cde</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">efg</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">hij</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

Comment: Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: @rguttersohn no, i am not using Vue Router. Should I use vue router?

Comment: Yes there are other utilities that would handle this, but Vue Router is made for Vue and is super easy. It allows you to add different static and dynamic links to pages in your single page app.

Comment: I see, I will add vue router thenn.. Thank you very much for the advice :) i really do appreciate it! However, if I have to use vue router, do I have to change the code above into something else? and what do I have to change the href="#" to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Once you read the documentation on Vue Router, it will all be clear how to add links to other "pages." Here is a link: https://router.vuejs.org/